# Why were 3 Qirat added later?

Tags: quran

I saw this video https://youtu.be/KrNity4tX4c

And he says that there are 7 and then those imam's students added the 3? I don't know if I'm misunderstanding but I thought 3 were added because the person who was collecting the Qirat was in a different area to where the 3 were? If they added 3 how can they trace it back to the prophet pbuh?

I also read this in an article by Yaqeen institute:

Some of those astray may resort to such reports to cast doubts and state: whoever recites according to a reading that conforms to the meaning of a ḥarf from the Qur’an is correct so long as he does not contradict the meaning or bring forth other than what Allah intended and meant, and they use as proof this statement of Anas ibn Mālik. And this argument is an empty claim that should not be relied upon nor should the one making it be paid any attention. And that is because if one were to recite according to words that differ with the wording of the Qur’an despite approximating its meaning and general intent, then it would be permissible to recite in place of “al-ḥamdu lillāhi rabbi al-ʿālamīn” the phrase “al-shukru lil-bārī malik al-makhlūqīn.” And the flexibility in this regard would continue to increase until the entire wording of the Qur’an was nullified and replaced with that which would be a fabrication upon God and a lie upon His Messenger

(https://yaqeeninstitute.org/ammar-khatib/the-origins-of-the-variant-readings-of-the-quran/#ftnt_ref99)

Does this mean that Qirat cannot be made up by somebody depending on whatever they feel is easier to recite? If so, then could somebody explain where the last 3 came from? I've heard the last 3 were masshur so I'm confused.

The article also has a reference (number 109) to this hadith  -
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Ubayy, I was asked to recite the Qur'an and I was asked: 'In one mode or two modes?' The angel that accompanied me said: 'Say, in two modes', I said: 'In two modes', I was asked again: 'In two or three modes'. The matter reached up to seven modes. He then said: 'Each mode is sufficiently health-giving, whether you utter 'all-hearing and all-knowing' or instead 'all-powerful and all-wise'. This is valid until you finish the verse indicating punishment on mercy and finish the verse indicating mercy on punishment.

Does this hadith mean that you can choose which name to recite as long as it doesn't conflict with the verse? Meaning you can decide on your own without it tracing back to the prophet pbuh having used that variant? Is that how the other 3 came about?

I've even once heard of somebody saying there are 25 qirat. Is this rejected? I don't understand the difference of opinion as we could be rejecting the Qur'an or accepting something we shouldnt. And also this means that different people would think there are different Qur'ans.

Comment: They didn't "add 3" more qiraat. In simple terms, the scholar wrote a book proving that (even though others had not realized it and thus did not count the 3) the 3 qiraat were also mutawatir confirmed from the Prophet SAW in addition to the other 7.

Comment: Sadly many people write about topics they don't really understand. There have been many qurra'a and qira'at ibn Mujahid chose 7 out of them and two rawys of each. His teacher imam at-Tabari has chosen 8 and he didn't consider Hafs from 'Asim in his tafsir at all. There have been many other choices, but somehow similarly to the 4 schools of fiqh people kept on concentrating on the choice of ibn Mujahid (even Shi' a who adopted the topic later). In fact one rather "artificial qira'a" is that of Hamza (one of the 7 qurra') who mixed the Kufi qira'at, but ibn Mujahid chose his riwaya.